# How can I see all my rejected edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I looked at one of my approved edits and found I had a whopping four rejected edits (that is much more than what I expected). I was able to see a snippet of a half a dozen recent edits and see the one that was rejected and I guessed why.

I would really like to see which others were rejected. How can I do that?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can also use [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to [search for your suggestions that were rejected or approved](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/752249/users-suggested-edits). (Or search for [rejected edits](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1799/my-rejected-edits) and [accepted edits](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1800/my-accepted-edits) separately.)

Since implementation of the ["Magic Column with arbitrary URL"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104772/158912) feature-request, I updated the queries and added a link to the suggested edit page itself.

Comment: @doncherry SEDE only supports post links and user links

Comment: does this still work? i couldn't make it do.

Comment: @naxa Yes, here is your accepted edits: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45756/my-accepted-edits?UserId=611007 and rejected: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45755/my-rejected-edits?UserId=611007

Comment: ah I finally understand, my userid is different on the different sites. :D I misinterpreted 'works on all sites' and I also have to switch the data explorer with the `switch sites` box (now to DE).

Comment: Is there a way to view my pending edits? they doesn't seem to be in this table.

Comment: Is there a way to see the reason it was rejected?

Comment: @naxa no as Data Explorer only contains historical data

Comment: @JeffBridgman currently no, but there is an open feature-request for adding rejection reason to `SuggestedEditVotes` table. You can vote for it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137364/158912

Comment: the link is working for approved edits, but not for rejected...

Comment: I made a fork of the query for showing pending edits, but I guess it'll never work (I guess Data Explorer doesn't use live data): http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/288422/my-pending-edits

Comment: Thank you!!
The rejection reason is now available, as requested.  Can you update the script?: [Please add suggested edit rejection reasons to SEDE - Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137364/please-add-suggested-edit-rejection-reasons-to-sede)

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to not work for http://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/45755/my-rejected-edits?UserId=79702 which should be showing an edit that got rejected at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241364/convert-xcursor-to-png -- or is there a delay more than an hour?

Comment: @entre It does work fine for me. Maybe you don't have any rejected reviews? :)

Comment: @Idolon can you add a query for pending ones please? :)

Comment: You can also bookmark the rejected and accepted edits by appending `?userid=xxxx` to the URL and replace xxxx with your user number. It will populate the UserId field automatically then.

Comment: Doesn't it work for [politics.se]?

Comment: I'm getting an error when I execute this: `Line 1: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_MSforeachdb', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.`

Comment: @M.Justin I got this error only at the start. I logged in via my SE account and tried again (make sure you're using the right userId, differs for each community). It works properly now for me and can't reproduce it. EDIT: deleted this comment by a misclick, put it back.

Comment: @jahu Are you sure? I just tried it and it worked for me! It showed my expected single result which still awaits approval.

Answer (score 32):

An old question, but still extremely relevant, and with a much easier answer 4 years on (did I mention that I love the new update? :D ):

1. At the top right of the screen, click on your user profile icon. This now takes you to a page like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2427542/aspiring-sarge) (sorry, this is my first meta.stackexchange post, so there's no activity on this site for my profile right now).
2. At the right of the screen, you'll see an `IMPACT` box. It shows how many posts you've edited. Click on the hyperlink there that reads `x posts edited`.
3. You've now effectively gone to `all actions > revisions`. Now, click on the `all actions > suggestions` sub-tab, and voila! A list of all edits, both accepted and rejected :D

Comment: For some reason this is not available on an across-all-communities basis via https://stackexchange.com/users/{SEuserID}?tab=activity&sort=suggestions so I have the following: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/752249/users-suggested-edits

Comment: I wish to only see `rejected edits`out of these...

Comment: It's a problem that you can't see only the rejected ones (and that you don't get informed when it's rejected); how will I improve as an editor?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin Not relevant to you anymore but for others, here's some advice.  Every 3-4 days say if you suggest an edit once a day, go to your profile page and then view "all actions". You'll see either "approve" or "reject", for suggestions that have been reviewed. Clicking either will show the stats and rejection reason (if rejected). Heck, I even checked my edits which were accepted to see if anybody edited over it, after all, our edits need to be as complete as possible. A good number of times I learnt what I had missed out.

Comment: @joeljpa, what he means is that he doesn't want to click <Next> 100 times (each page shows only 20 per) and ctrl-F a 100 times, just to seek the few rejected ones. He also doesn't want to bother with data.SE for something that should be so simple.

Answer (score 4):

There's no convenient way, on your own and without a ♦, to see your history of edit suggestions short of keeping track of them yourself. Diamonds possess a limitted ability to view the history of edit suggestions of users, so you might be able to ask one to help you.

As a normal user, you can hackshod your way into finding out, though, by first finding any of your edit suggestions (approved or rejected), and checking the edit suggestion page. At the bottom will be a list of "recent edits", which will shuffle based on what edit suggestion you're looking at. The length of time this will take to sift through depends on your volume of suggestions, but I've successfully used it to review 30 of my edit suggestions once, so it should be able to find your rejections if you keep at it.

Comment: You may want to change the 'there is' to 'was' with a strike-see above :)

Comment: @Manishearth Honestly, pointing out the (rather old by this point, but relative to this question) new ["suggestions" tab](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/3588/grace-note?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) would be the better point here.